# GCC: make sources built-in into binary

Tags: gcc, gdb

I have a program that I need to debug on remote machine.
Due to the issue character it should be run in a certain way, that I can't reproduce simply running there, so I put a sleep before the problematic area.

I am able to attach to the process with `gdb` during this sleep period, but I don't have source files on the remote machine.

Is it possible to compile program the way that sources will be built-in into binary itself?

Comment: Added an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, that is not possible.

Another way is to just `rsync` the sources onto the remote machine.